# Partial application of map function

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming, partial-application

Just defined a generic `map` function in Swift:

```swift
func map<T, S: Sequence>(_ f: @escaping (S.Element) -> T) -> (S) -> [T] {
    return { xs in xs.map(f) }
}
```

However, when I try to partially apply the identity function...

```swift
map({ $0 })
```

the compiler says:

> No exact matches in call to global function 'map'

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Idk why it’s give that particular error, but one of the issues here is at S and T are undetermined at your call site

Comment: Thank you, @Alexander. Makes sense. Do you know a way to partially apply a function in this manner ?

Comment: You’ll have to provide the type data, either by adding type annotations on your closure (I.e. specify the parameter and return type) or on the return type of map

Comment: Something like this, @Alexander ? `let f : ([Int]) -> [Int] =  map( {$0} )` ?

Comment: @F.Zer can you please add some more context to your question?

Comment: How can I add a type annotation to the closure ?

Comment: I guess partial application is not going to be very useful if I have to annotate everything beforehand.

Comment: `{ x: Int -> [Whatever] in }`

Comment: Sure, @LeoDabus. What kind of context ?

Comment: I just tested your suggestion, but it does not work, @LeoDabus. For example: `map({ x: (Int) -> Int in x })`. It says: Cannot find x in scope.

Comment: @F.Zer my bad you need to put it inside parentheses `(x: Int)` => `let f: ([Int]) -> [Int] = map { (x: Int) -> Int in x }`

Comment: Good. Now, it works perfectly, @LeoDabus.